# Oracle to MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, oracle, syntax

Can someone show me the MySQL equivalent of the following statement (which works in Oracle 10g)?

```
INSERT INTO VOUCHER (VOUCHER_NUMBER, BOOK_ID, DENOMINATION) 
  SELECT a.a1, b.ID, b.DENOMINATION FROM (SELECT rownum a1 
                                            FROM dual 
                                      CONNECT BY rownum <= 10000000) a, BOOK b
  WHERE a.a1 BETWEEN b.START_NUMBER AND b.START_NUMBER + b.UNITS - 1;
```

Basically, what this is doing is for every entry in the table `BOOK`, it is making entries in the table `VOUCHER`. The number of entries in the `VOUCHER` table is determined by the number of `UNITS` in the corresponding row in the `BOOK` table. I can provide more information if this is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main weirdness going on here is the `SELECT ROWNUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY...` -- a kludge that's giving you incrementing numbers starting at the value of BOOKS.START_NUMBER; those then seem to be used as primary keys in the VOUCHER table.

Really, this is a symptom of an awful underlying data model: keeping track of the "start number" and "units" in a table -- it's like a C array gone bad in a database.

If you're taking the time to port this from Oracle to MySQL, seriously give some thought to fixing the data model. Perhaps you want to:

- add a book_id column to the VOUCHER table and subsequent foreign key to the BOOK table
- make the VOUCHER_NUMBER column on the new VOUCHER table in MySQL to be an auto-increment type so you can eliminate the whole start number / units mess

With those in place, use whatever language you're using to implement business logic in MySQL and implement this pseudo-code:

```
for 1 to BOOK.units loop

  INSERT INTO VOUCHER (
      -- VOUCHER_NUMBER handled by auto-increment
      BOOK_ID
    , DENOMINATION
  )
  SELECT 
      b.ID
    , b.DENOMINATION
  FROM BOOK b
  WHERE b.ID = [book ID];

end loop
```

Comment: I don't see it as a terrible kludge. Joining with a big table is a standard practice for pivoting relational sets of data.

Comment: And using auto-increment wouldn't work... the voucher numbers are only guaranteed to be incrementing within a book, but books don't have to be sequential.

Comment: @Nick: perhaps not a terrible kludge, but one nonetheless; in what environment is this used for pivoting rather than the case/decode method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365238/advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle

Comment: @Elie: without more information, there's no guarantee in your original SQL that voucher numbers will increment "properly" either since there's no control over what's in BOOKS.START_NUMBER. If the data model won't be fixed, at least clearly define the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The select from `DUAL` is effectively giving you a large temporary table to join with `BOOK`. You are allowing for `BOOK.UNITS` to have values up to 10,000,000.

If units is typically a lot lower than this one option would be to create a dummy table with that number of records in it and join to that instead of the `DUAL` construct.