# Pivot Table in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Could you please help me to figure out the pivot table? here is the first table :

```
Date        1     2     3     4     5
-----------------------------------------
20130101   0.12  0.13  0.43  0.32  0.22
20130102   0.22  0.31  0.13  0.31  0.29
20130103   0.32  0.12  0.33  0.12  0.34
```

I want this table to be like this :

```
Date      Number  Values
---------------------------
20130101     1     0.12
20130101     2     0.13
20130101     3     0.43
20130101     4     0.32
20130102     5     0.22
20130102     1     0.22
20130102     2     0.31
20130102     3     0.13
20130102     4     0.31
20130102     5     0.29
20130103     1     0.32
20130103     2     0.12
20130103     3     0.33
20130103     4     0.12
20130103     5     0.34
```

I've tried to find the specific query for this like using "decode", but it didn't work for me.

here is a website that I've tried : 
[Advice Using Pivot Table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365238/advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle).

Could you please help me to figure this out?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: BTW, Why do you use reserved words as your column names? and is the "Date" column a varchar2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a [`PIVOT` but an `UNPIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
unpivot
(
  "Values" FOR "Number" IN ("1","2","3","4","5")
 );
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcfe6/1)