# Crosstab or transpose query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, crosstab, transpose

I have a result set from a query like this

```
mon-yar Count   EB      VC
Apr-11    34    1237    428
May-11    54    9834    87
Jun-11    23    9652    235
Jul-11    567   10765   1278
Aug-11    36    10234   1092
Sep-11    78    8799    987
Oct-11    23    10923   359
Nov-11    45    11929   346
Dec-11    67    9823    874
Jan-12    45    2398    245
Feb-12    90    3487    937
Mar-12   123    7532    689
Apr-12   109    1256    165
```

What I wish is this:

```
monthyear   Apr-11  May-11  Jun-11  Jul-11  Aug-11  Sep-11  Oct-11  Nov-11  Dec-11  Jan-12  Feb-12  Mar-12  Apr-12
Count           34      54      23     567      36      78      23      45      67      45      90     123     109
EB            1237    9834    9652   10765   10234    8799   10923   11929    9823    2398    3487    7532    1256
VC             428      87     235    1278    1092     987     359     346     874     245     937     689     165
```

The Month Year values are dynamic. What can I do to generate it this way?

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz: Pivoting for dynamic list of columns and multiple items is very complex to manage. I am looking at a better approach if available.

Comment: Excel is a right tool to format table this way (a.k.a Pivot Table)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advice Using Pivot Table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365238/advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle)

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use PIVOT, you can use the solution below, as long as you don't mind using text to columns in Excel upon the result.

If you were to run:

```
with tbl as(
select 'Apr-11' as monyar, 34 as cnt, 1237 as eb, 428 as vc from dual union all
select 'May-11' as monyar, 54 as cnt, 9834 as eb, 87 as vc from dual union all
select 'Jun-11' as monyar, 23 as cnt, 9652 as eb, 235 as vc from dual union all
select 'Jul-11' as monyar, 567 as cnt, 10765 as eb, 1278 as vc from dual union all
select 'Aug-11' as monyar, 36 as cnt, 10234 as eb, 1092 as vc from dual union all
select 'Sep-11' as monyar, 78 as cnt, 8799 as eb, 987 as vc from dual union all
select 'Oct-11' as monyar, 23 as cnt, 10923 as eb, 359 as vc from dual union all
select 'Nov-11' as monyar, 45 as cnt, 11929 as eb, 346 as vc from dual union all
select 'Dec-11' as monyar, 67 as cnt, 9823 as eb, 874 as vc from dual union all
select 'Jan-12' as monyar, 45 as cnt, 2398 as eb, 245 as vc from dual union all
select 'Feb-12' as monyar, 90 as cnt, 3487 as eb, 937 as vc from dual union all
select 'Mar-12' as monyar, 123 as cnt, 7532 as eb, 689 as vc from dual union all
select 'Apr-12' as monyar, 109 as cnt, 1256 as eb, 165 as vc from dual
)
select 'Month' as lbl, listagg(monyar,' | ') within group (order by monyar) as list from tbl
union all
select 'Count' as lbl, listagg(cnt,' | ') within group (order by monyar) as list from tbl
union all
select 'EB' as lbl, listagg(eb,' | ') within group (order by monyar) as list from tbl
union all
select 'VC' as lbl, listagg(vc,' | ') within group (order by monyar) as list from tbl
```

Result:

```
LBL     LIST
Month   Apr-11 | Apr-12 | Aug-11 | Dec-11 | Feb-12 | Jan-12 | Jul-11 | Jun-11 | Mar-12 | May-11 | Nov-11 | Oct-11 | Sep-11
Count   34 | 109 | 36 | 67 | 90 | 45 | 567 | 23 | 123 | 54 | 45 | 23 | 78
EB      1237 | 1256 | 10234 | 9823 | 3487 | 2398 | 10765 | 9652 | 7532 | 9834 | 11929 | 10923 | 8799
VC      428 | 165 | 1092 | 874 | 937 | 245 | 1278 | 235 | 689 | 87 | 346 | 359 | 987
```

Using the pipe as the delimitter you can then split the 2nd column into however many columns there are.

LISTAGG is an Oracle function and I'm not sure there is a 1:1 equivalent in sql server, so you would have to mimic the vertical concatenation one way or another, if it has to be run in sql server.