# "pivot" table Oracle - how to change row items into columns

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I have the following simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars ( Cars, Item, Value ) AS
SELECT 'bmw',      'wheels', '4'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bmw',      'color',  'red'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bmw',      'price',  '5'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mercedes', 'wheels', '4'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mercedes', 'color',  'black'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lambo',    'wheels', '5'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lambo',    'color',  'yellow' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lambo',    'price',  '7'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mercedes', 'price',  '6'      FROM DUAL;
```

The thing is that I need to "pivot" the table to get items as column names with values as values and everything grouped together (row with unique car name and no null values in cells). Hence I wrote "pivot", because classic pivoting (DECODE) leads to different result - decreasing skew values in cells and a lot of null values. So it would looks like this

```
car      wheels color  price
-------- ------ ------ -----
bmw           4    red     5
lambo         5 yellow     7
mercedes      4  black     6
```

**So the question:**

Should I do this via procedures or is there any more elegant solution? Procedure would be following (in pseudocode):

```
1. create table cars2 /*columns are known in before, wheels/color/price*/
2. get the distinct names of the cars and insert them into collection /*eg nested table*/
3.    for each car do
insert into table cars2
values per item /*looping items and inserting corresponding values*/
```

OK, code seems simple. But having more than half a milion of records and 15 items, and updating the table once a hour may lead to real performance problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advice Using Pivot Table in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365238/advice-using-pivot-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the query below;-

```
  select * from
  (select cars, item,value from carTable) 
  pivot(max(value) for item in ('wheels', 'color', 'price'))
```

Comment: Thank You. It works but have no idea why - that max aggregate on varchar columns confuses me... I suspect it doesnt calculate but has to be there because has to be...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cars,
       MAX( CASE item WHEN 'color'  THEN value END ) AS color,
       MAX( CASE item WHEN 'price'  THEN value END ) AS price,
       MAX( CASE item WHEN 'wheels' THEN value END ) AS wheels
FROM   Cars
GROUP BY cars;
```

**Outputs**:

```
CARS     PRICE COLOR  WHEELS
-------- ----- ------ ------
lambo    7     yellow 5
mercedes 6     black  4
bmw      5     red    4
```