# SQL query to fetch details when one of value is missing

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a table with entries for students:

```
  cloumn1      key         value
  -------------------------------
  john         age            23
  john         salary        100
  John          rollno        12
  Raj          age            24
  Raj          rollno         10
```

I want to get result of salary value when queried on salary and student 
name.

It is always queried on salary and student. For the second student since salary record itself is not there. I am facing the issue in fetching the records

```
SELECT 
    a.id, b.location, c.value
FROM 
    boys A, school B,details c
WHERE 
    A.id = B.id
    c.id = a.id
    c.key = salary
```

Request every one to throw your solutions

Thanks in advance

Comment: show me your query.

Comment: There are many reasons why the Entity-Attribute-Value "model" is widely loathed amongst database practitioners, and its propensity to lose data like this is one of them. Model proper tables. You have an Oracle database, use it. Or if that is too restrictive use JSON or some other NoSQL data store. Obviously that won't solve the problem of missing data but at least it's more honest.

Comment: @jyotimishra..added the query in the question now

Comment: The objects referenced by your query don't match the table you posted previously.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35791681/1509264

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( CASE key WHEN 'salary' THEN value END ) AS salary
FROM   details
GROUP BY id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   details
PIVOT  ( MAX( value )
         FOR key IN (
           'salary' AS salary,
           'rollno' AS rollno,
           'age'    AS age
       ) );
```